# Display Mulitple Feeds in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Attempting to display multiple feeds in Full Calendar.  Have script below working, but not properly.  On initial page load only one feed displays. After refreshing browser, a different feed displays.  When navigating through the calendar, get a different feed on each view.  If click back to month view, all 3 feeds display, but list same info 3 times each.  Console does not return any errors or warnings.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ){
                var objectdata = {
                        where: {
                            'Datetime.DTT_EVT_start': [
                                '>', start.format() + 'T00:00:00'
                            ],
                            'Datetime.DTT_EVT_end': [
                                '<', end.format() + 'T00:00:00'
                            ]
                        },
                        "include": 'Datetime.*'
                    };
                
                const cals = [
                    'https://feed1.org/wp-json/v4.8.29/events',
                    'https://feed2.org/wp-json/v4.8.29/events',
                    'https://feed3.org/wp-json/v4.8.29/events',
                ];
                
        
                const events = [];
                for (let index = 0; index < cals.length; ++index) {
                    const element = cals[index];
                    console.log(element);
                    console.log(index);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: element,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: objectdata,
                        success: function(doc) {
                            $(doc).each(function() {
                                //only add events to the calendar if they have a datetime (they all should)
                                if( this.datetimes[0] ){
                                    events.push({
                                        title: this.EVT_name,
                                        url:  this.link,
                                        start: this.datetimes[0].DTT_EVT_start,// will be parsed
                                        end: this.datetimes[0].DTT_EVT_end // will be parsed
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                            callback(events);
                        },
                        error: function( xhr, status, error ) {
                            alert('error communicating with server: ' + status );
                        }
                    });
                }
                    
            }
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I think you can only really use `callback(events);` once in each event feed. Each time you call it, it's likely to overwrite the events for that feed.

Comment: Instead of using one event feed to try and load data from multiple URLs, I'd recommend to define each of your feeds as a separate event source in fullCalendar - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventSources